# kotest nested spec in describe clause

Tags: kotlin, kotlintest, kotest

I've started using kotest:4.0.5 (kotlintest) and having problem with `stringSpec` function nested in  `describe` clause.

Example:

```kotlin
class SellerTest : DescribeSpec({

    describe("Registration") {
        context("Not existing user") {
            include(emailValidation()
        }
    }
})

fun emailValidation() = stringSpec {
    "Email validation" {
        forAll(
            row("test.com"),
            row("123123123123123")
        ) { email ->
            assertSoftly {
                val exception =
                    shouldThrow<ServiceException> { Email(email) }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

If `include(emailValidation())` is outside `describe` clause then correctly works.

Have you any idea how to nest specs/functions in clauses?

Answer (score 2):

You can only use `include` at the top level. This is part of how factory tests (what the include keyword is used for) are implemented (perhaps that will be relaxed in a future release).

You can move the whole thing into the factory though.

```
class SellerTest : DescribeSpec({
  include(emailValidation)
})

val emailValidation = describeSpec {

    describe("Registration") {
        context("Not existing user") {
            forAll(
                row("test.com"),
                row("123123123123123")
            ) { email ->
                assertSoftly {
                    val exception =
                        shouldThrow<ServiceException> { Email(email) }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you can parameterize the naming all you want, as that's just strings, for example:

```
fun emailValidation(name: String) = describeSpec {
    describe("Registration") {
        context("$name") {
        }
    }
}
```

If you are not parameterizing, then there's little point in having the test factory. Just declare the test inline IMO.

Comment: Thanks, Honestly its not what I dreamed about ^^. I thought someone will have magic solution. Hopefully it will change in future.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve vs what I showed. Maybe there's some other way of getting the same result.

Comment: Email validation is part of registration process so it cannot be like that. I wanted to nest it in registration describe. But if its not possible then probably will include it out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

For nested `include` you may implement your own factory method like this example:

```
class FactorySpec : FreeSpec() {
    init {
        "Scenario: root container" - {
            containerTemplate()
        }
    }
}

/** Add [TestType.Container] by scope function extension */
suspend inline fun FreeScope.containerTemplate(): Unit {
    "template container with FreeScope context" - {
        testCaseTemplate()
    }
}

/** Add [TestType.Test] by scope function extension */
suspend inline fun FreeScope.testCaseTemplate(): Unit {
    "nested template testcase with FreeScope context" { }
}
```

Pay attention to the `Scope` that is passed to the extension function for `containerTemplate` and `testCaseTemplate`

Output:

```
Scenario: root container
   template container with FreeScope context
       nested template testcase with FreeScope context
```